# why does a file has different names in nautilus and terminal

Tags: terminal, filenames, ubuntu-16.04, nautilus

when I look up in nautilus for a Desktop file it has the filename showed below:

[image]

Then I open in terminal and search for the same file, I found it has another name showed below:

[image]

Anybody knows why it is like this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you `cat` the file in the terminal you will see the `PyCharm` name inside it. That's simply how `.desktop` files work. They are in a way similar to shortcuts in Windows. You can read all about it in the [desktop entry specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

Comment: Got it. Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to .desktop files.

> In GNOME and other freedesktop.org-compliant desktops, an application
>   gets registered into the desktop's menus through a desktop entry,
>   which is a text file with .desktop extension. This desktop file
>   contains a listing of the configurations for your application.

More information can be found here https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en